# how to incorporate mixed fractions into English

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, fractions

### For example, when writing a recipe which should you use?

1. one and a half cup
2. one and a half cups
3. one cup and a half
4. a cup and a half
5. a cup and half
6. three halves of a cup

### Also, if you were to use fractions in a sentence, are these two grammatically okay?

> - The stages 3 and 4 lasts a little more than *half an hour*.
> - The stages 3 and 4 lasts a little more than *a half  hour*.

Please tell me which are correct and wrong. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: For the first, 2 and 4 are "correct" (4 is questionable). For the second, neither is okay. The "stages 3 and 4" is singular, so "The stages 3 and 4 last  a little longer than a(n) half hour" - use "an" if you do not pronounce the "h" in "half", if you do pronounce the "h" it is "a half hour".

Comment: Maybe 4 is a bit more informal but it is a very common utterance- not questionable at all.

Comment: @Jim But is it *one cup and an half* or *one cup and a half*.

Comment: Definitely ***a*** half.  (I pronounce the ’h’ in half) But I could see a dialect transcribed as  “a cup an’ an ’alf.”

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+an+half%3Aeng_gb_2009%2C+and+a+half%3Aeng_gb_2009%2Cand+an+half%3Aeng_us_2009%2C+and+a+half%3Aeng_us_2009&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20an%20half%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20a%20half%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20an%20half%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20a%20half%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0

Comment: If you're listing ingredients to someone, you might use different (correct) forms so it isn't so monotonous.

Answer (score 1):

*How would I express a fraction?*

The specific example you chose, recipes, are a bit idiomatic because they generally use arabic numerals {1 1\2}.

Use of fractions in roman text is a style issue and may change from guide to guide. The key potential difference is hyphenation.

[Using the *Chicago Manual of Style*]

**One-and-a-half cups** In this case, *one-and-a-half* operates as a compound adjective.

Some other examples: three-fourths, thirty percent loss, one hundred twenty-three and thirty-seven cents, I am one and a half, I am one-and-a-half years old

Time has a separate set of rules, but there is also overlap:

{I am three-and-a-half hours away},{I went on a three-hour cruise},{It is three thirty},{It is three twenty-seven},{It is three o'clock},{Four o'clock tea time},{Flight 897 arrives at three thirty},{half-hour ride will start in a half hour},{Both three am and three AM are acceptable, as are three a.m. and three A.M., but it's best to use arabic numerals at that point}.